# Trying to pinpoint code being added to wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I've just started doing some website work for a local business, and I noticed today that there's a very unwanted link at the bottom of their site, which is a wordpress site.

The site makes use of a woo theme called 'whiteLight', as well as woocommerce. I've tried disabling and reenabling all plugins that aren't well known and integral to the site's functioning, and I've sifted through a lot of the theme's files.

I can't find where this line is being added to the site. The line "`<center>*bad link here*</center>`" is being inserted right after the header and right before the closing body tag, on the home page only. The link in question is actually linking to naughty files inside a directory within the wordpress installation. It's not even taking users to an ouside site as far as I can tell.

I don't have FTP access to the wordpress directory yet, but I've requested it. I have very little experience with wordpress hooks etc, and am hoping someone can help me find a starting point in weeding out this unwanted link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: once you have ftp access mirror the entire site locally and start with a file search for the offending url or a fragment of it. - if that doesn't find it eeak!

Comment: is it a free theme ? if not , have you got a blackhat copy from somewhere ?

Comment: You know, I'm not sure how legit everything is, but I may try to start over with current themes etc anyway. Wordfence really helped uncover the depth of the issues! Good advice, Norlesh. Now I'll work on getting mysql etc running locally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordFence is the best security plugin for WordPress. I'd recommend you follow the instructions at https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/

Another good resource to read is https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

I recommend you search all the files as norlesh suggested. If this was my problem I'd use Jetbrains PHPStorm to search all the files. Another much cheaper solution would be to use Textpad - https://www.textpad.com/

It's also possible that the link has been inserted into your database. If so you won't find it in your files. You'll have to search the database. Use a program like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench to export the whole database to your machine. Then search the sql file for the URL. Alternatively use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ which is a handy tool you upload to the server. From there you enter db login details and search the database. Note if you use this script you should delete if off your server when you've finished using it, it's a huge security risk.

Comment: Wordfence was just the thing to uncover many altered files. Now I suppose the smart thing to do is make a local clone to see if the site can be fixed, and if not, start over preserving whatever I can. Any advice regarding the easiest method of running wordpress locally? I used to have php/sql/etc installed years ago, but it's been a while. All the info is appreciated.

Comment: Generally the procedure is Download the files, modify wp_config.php with new connection details, import the db and then use interconnectit tool to change url.

Comment: Make a new mysql user to handle that db restricted permissions. You don't want malicious code wrecking any other db.